# ^R in iTerm with tmux with zshell killing pane, not showing history

Tags: tmux, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I use iTerm2 with `oh-my-zsh`. Whenever my terminal is open, I have tmux running. I updated iTerm recently and now my Ctrl+R closes each tmux pane until tmux is killed, then it'll kill iTerm, too.  It used to open up the history plugin `history-search-multi-word` that I use in `oh-my-zsh`. I'm not sure how to track down what is capturing it.  Any ideas?

My dotfiles (including iterm2 json export file) are located here: https://github.com/sahellebusch/.dotfiles

Comment: Whoa, this just in: when I run `source ~/.zshrc` it closes a pane! What?!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the line `alias source='source ~/.zshrc'` was causing the issue.  Believe is has something to do with perpetual expansion of the alias. Once removed, everything is back to normal.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a very bad alias to define. Either define a safer function like `source () { builtin source ~/.zshrc }` (which avoids the infinite recursion), or pick a better alias name.